# How to run a nested javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I am new to object orientated programming in javascript and am trying to understand some functions in a project I am working on.

How would I call/run the internal function (the one listed 'this.getFieldset = function() {') to execute?

```
function Fieldset() {

    this.id = "";
    this.content = document.createElement("DIV");
    this.content.id = "content";
    this.title = "Title";

    this.getFieldset = function() {

        var div = document.createElement("DIV");
        div.id = this.id;
        var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        var fieldset = document.createElement("DIV");
        fieldset.id = "fieldset";
        var header = document.createElement("DIV");
        header.id = "header";
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.title));
        header.appendChild(span);
        div.appendChild(header);
        div.appendChild(this.content);
        div.appendChild(fieldset);

        return div;
    }
}

var myFieldset = new Fieldset();
myFieldset.getFieldset();
```

Comment: I recommend to read through [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: from where would you like to execute it?

Answer (score 5):

First you should create an instance of `Fieldset`, then you'll be able to call its functions (called methods):

```
var myFieldset = new Fieldset();

myFieldset.getFieldset();
```

Comment: I thought when running this it would make what I presumed myFieldset.getFieldset() would run which is create a DIV, SPAN, etc. Don't mean to make this out of scope, but shouldn't that write to the page?

Comment: @peteskiii: No. You don't append the created `div` anywhere. It is returned by `getFieldset`, so do something with it ;)

Comment: but when i run this code, nothing happens at all, i don't see anything in the object inspector?

Answer (score -1):

```
    function Fieldset() {

    this.id = "";
    this.content = document.createElement("DIV");
    this.content.id = "content";
    this.title = "Title";

    this.getFieldset = function() {

        var div = document.createElement("DIV");
        div.id = this.id;
        var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        //var fieldset = document.createElement("DIV");
        //fieldset.id = "fieldset";
        var header = document.createElement("DIV");
        header.id = "header";
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.title));
        header.appendChild(span);
        div.appendChild(header);
        div.appendChild(this.content);
        div.appendChild(fieldset);

        window.alert("test");

        return div;
    }

    //add call to run function
    this.getFieldset();

}
```

Comment: I think he means from OUTSIDE the implementation.

Comment: Since he didn't imply that, I didn't assume. You know what they say about assumptions.

Comment: I have tried to update the code example to better show what I am trying to achieve.